# Appcompat-v7:27.1.1 style error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-studio-3.0, android-appcompat

my application suddenly started to throw this error:

> error: :style>.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: :style>., sources=
>   [.../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7->27.1.1.aar/6841cb0f36d8ca017bbed63b78588e52/res/values/values.xml:1586:5->1587:13], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

and this is the line it is pointing at:

> parent="Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat">

i uninstalled support repository from sdk manager and reinstalled it! but it didn't solve the problem!

this is my usage of support libraries in app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project after delete build folder.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work out! problem still exists!

Comment: based on comments on this medium post [https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-fix-android-studio-3-1-error-debugging-issue-8d06ad9f49a9] i think the problem is for android studio 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after i created a new project and added all classes and assets one by one, i finally found the problem.
the problem was in my style.xml and because of one bad style definition!
there were a nested style definition! some thing like this:

```
<style name="someThing">
   ...
   <style name="anotherStyle">
      ...
   </style>
</style>
```

i think android studio 3.1.3 can do better in pointing out the problem!
thank you!